# I use React Router 4 in React page but I can't see my component in Route path

Tags: reactjs, react-router

[

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router , Route } from "react-router-dom";

const NewRout = () => {
  return(
    <p> MY ROUTE </p>
  );
}
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <Router>
          <Route path="/signin" Component={NewRout} />
        </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTXRI.png)I'm using router in my react page. But I can't see output.
I import BrowserRouter and Route from react-route-dom
and try to show mt component inside the route.but this is not working for me.Please help me how to solve this issue. Thanks

```
<BrowserRouter><Route path="signin" Component={Signin} /></BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: Does the URL changes?

Comment: no the URL is same

Comment: Please include more code.

Comment: what do you mean by not working

Comment: i have not any output

Comment: `import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router , Route } from "react-router-dom";

const NewRout = () => {
  return(
    <p> MY ROUTE </p>
  );
}
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <Router>
          <Route path="/signin" Component={NewRout} />
        </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a mistake in your path:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "./styles.css";

const Home = () => (
  <h1>
    Home <Link to="/signin">SING</Link>
  </h1>
);

const SingIn = () => (
  <h1>
    <Link to="/">Home</Link>
    This is singin page
  </h1>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/signin" component={SingIn} />
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </div>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Now locate to `http://localhost:port/singin` you will see your component.

Note: I added a `/` before your path. This denotes that you are going to `signin` from your root that is `/`.

You need to use a prop called `exact` which matches for exact Route.

Try this `SandBox`

https://codesandbox.io/s/moj8kxp0nx

Comment: i add "/signin" but still empty my page

Comment: Can you paste the complete code of your `index` and `signin` files

Comment: import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router , Route } from "react-router-dom";

const NewRout = () => {
  return(
    <p> MY ROUTE </p>
  );
}
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <Router>
          <Route path="/signin" Component={NewRout} />
        </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;

Comment: import React from "react";

const Signin = () => {
    return(
        <h1> Sign in Page </h1>
    );
}

export default Signin;

Comment: Just Updated my Answer try the codesand box link and the answer.
If it works please give it an upvote and accept it as the answer, appreciable for my efforts thanks.